# getting parameters for jython module

Tags: websphere, jython

I'm trying to figure out how to get parameters that trickle into my jython websphere related module. I obviously don't understand this so any help is appreciated. Here is what I'm trying which is completely unsatisfactory/nonfunctional:

```
execfile('wsadminlib.py')
Opts = {}
for key in Opts.key() :
  print(' option passed in is: ' + key)

#for c in listServerClusters():
#    startCluster(c);
#    print(c + ' status: ' + str(isClusterStarted(c)) )
```

Comment: What are the contents of `wsadminlib.py`? What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Since you define `Opts` as `{}`, it will be empty when you try iterating over its keys (should be `Opts.keys()` not `Opts.key()`).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to read properties defined in another file/module, you can `import` them. For example:

**properties.py**

```
properties = {
    'prop1': 'test'
}

def get():
    return properties
```

**script.py**

```
import properties

properties = properties.get()

print(properties['prop1'])
```